# How do we change navbar while browsing in different component in Vue?

Tags: vue.js, navbar

I have 3 Different Navbar components. I wanted to change the display of the navbar for one of the student components and one for employees.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/FrBav.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VYNfa.png

Comment: Could you give more details, in special how you switch between student component and employees

Comment: I have kept the image above.

Comment: I have the two other navbar in the components. after login I wanted the navbar to change accordingly

Comment: You can use url params to indicate which navbar to show, for example: site.com/student (will display navbar for student), site.com/employer (will display navbar for employer)

Comment: I didn't quite understand. could you perhaps give an example. Thank you

Comment: Example: https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-cloud-dd73f?file=/src/components/home.vue